# Archive instead of delete in Outlook 2016.

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016, when I press the delete key, I want to archive the email instead of deleting it.

Or alternatively, set Outlook up such that it never empties the deleted folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: I usually create a separate "Archive" PST file and move email to the archive.  I date by year and separate by incoming and outgoing and segregate between businesses and personal via folders and sub-folders.  I can usually move emails over in bulk to the archive in a matter of a few hours 1-2 times a year.  In the meantime I don't "get rid" of anything of any importance; they are there until I archive them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change the default key binding within Outlook, There could be a 3rd party addon for it but not by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the Delete group, choose Archive. You can also use the **Backspace** key to immediately archive one or more selected messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new .pst file and then copy the emails into it. Don't forget to close the newly created .pst file when you have finished. When you need to look at the emails again, just open the .pst file via outlook.